# Simplification of the expression

Tags: real-analysis

When I am solving a problem I got the following expression. Can somebody help me to simplify this?

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} \exp\left(\frac{-x_i}{k^2+2\ell^2{x_i}}\right)$$

where

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i=1$$
$$k,\ell \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$0 \leq k,\ell^2 \leq 1$$

I am trying to eliminate $x_i$ from the above expression by using the above information.

Comment: It's too small for me to read, but maybe you can't eliminate $x_i$. Try using two different sets of $x_i$. If you get different answers, then you can't eliminate $x_i$.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand the second sentence can you please explain.

Comment: Pick some $k$ and $\ell$. Then try, say, $x_1=1/3$, $x_2=2/3$. Next try, say, $x_1=1/4$, $x_2=3/4$. If you get two different numbers, then you can't eliminate the $x_i$, because the value of the expression depends on the $x_i$, and not just on their sum.